# Why am I getting the error "No overload for method 'CalculateProceeds' takes 0 arguments"

Tags: c#, overloading

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //declare variables

            int casesSold;
            int costPerCase = 5; //Each case costs the Computer Club $5
            int numBars = 12; //There are 12 candy bars in each case

            double salePrice;
            double forSGA = .9; //The Student Government Association (SGA) will collect 10% of the earnings that the Computer Club makes

            string aCasesSold;
            string aSalePrice;

            //ask user for information

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many cases were sold:  ");
            aCasesSold = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the sale price per candy bar: ");
            aSalePrice = Console.ReadLine();

            //Convert ints to strings so that they can be a part of the calculations

            casesSold = int.Parse(aCasesSold);
            salePrice = double.Parse(aSalePrice);

            //calculate total cost for the Computer Club

            public static double CalculateTotalCost(double totalCost, int costPerCase, int casesSold)

            {
               totalCost = costPerCase * casesSold;
               return totalCost; 

            }

            //calculate earnings for the Computer Club

            public static double CalculateEarnings(int numBars, int casesSold, double earnings, double salePrice)

            {

                earnings = numBars * salePrice * casesSold;
                return earnings;

            }

            //calculate proceeds

            public static double CalculateProceeds(double proceeds, double forSGA, double earnings, double totalCost)

            {

                proceeds = (forSGA * earnings) - totalCost;
                return proceeds;

            }

            //output proceeds to user

            public static void Output()

            {

                Console.WriteLine("The proceeds for the Computer Club are: {0;C}", CalculateProceeds());

            }
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am getting the following two errors:

"} expected" at end of `salePrice = double.Parse(aSalePrice);`

and

"No overload for method 'CalculateProceeds' takes 0 arguments"

I'm not sure how to make the Console Write my ending part, may you help me?
I also am not sure why Visual Studio thinks that I need to add a "}" at the end of `salePrice = double.Parse(aSalePrice);`

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

Comment: There's no `CalculateProceeds()` method in your code

Comment: You're declaring your methods inside your `main` method. They should be in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `}` from your `main` method and your call to `CalculateProceeds()` is missing its arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            //declare variables    
            int casesSold;
            int costPerCase = 5; //Each case costs the Computer Club $5
            int numBars = 12; //There are 12 candy bars in each case

            double salePrice;
            double forSGA = .9; //The Student Government Association (SGA) will collect 10% of the earnings that the Computer Club makes

            string aCasesSold;
            string aSalePrice;

            //ask user for information    
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many cases were sold:  ");
            aCasesSold = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the sale price per candy bar: ");
            aSalePrice = Console.ReadLine();

            //Convert ints to strings so that they can be a part of the calculations    
            casesSold = int.Parse(aCasesSold);
            salePrice = double.Parse(aSalePrice);

        } // was missing.

        //calculate total cost for the Computer Club                
        public static double CalculateTotalCost(double totalCost, int costPerCase, int casesSold)    
        {
           totalCost = costPerCase * casesSold;
           return totalCost;     
        }

        //calculate earnings for the Computer Club    
        public static double CalculateEarnings(int numBars, int casesSold, double earnings, double salePrice)    
        {    
            earnings = numBars * salePrice * casesSold;
            return earnings;    
        }

        //calculate proceeds    
        public static double CalculateProceeds(double proceeds, double forSGA, double earnings, double totalCost)    
        {    
            proceeds = (forSGA * earnings) - totalCost;
            return proceeds;    
        }

        //output proceeds to user    
        public static void Output()    
        {    
            Console.WriteLine("The proceeds for the Computer Club are: {0;C}", CalculateProceeds(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature for CalculateProceeds accepts 4 arguments

```
public static double CalculateProceeds(double proceeds, double forSGA, double earnings, double totalCost)
```

but you are trying to call it with out passing any of these arguments into the method

```
Console.WriteLine("The proceeds for the Computer Club are: {0;C}", CalculateProceeds());
```

Also you are declaring methods inside the main method which won't work.